# Why can I choose severity as filter, but not textPayload when using log based metrics in Metric Explorer

Tags: google-cloud-platform, stackdriver, google-cloud-stackdriver

I am trying to extract some metrics using the metrics explorer. I select the metric: `Log Entries` and resource `GKE`.
As far as I understand from the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/reference/v2/rest/v2/LogEntry) both `severity` and `textPayload` fields are first-class citizen, but I am able to select the `severity` field (and also `log`) but no `textPayload` (both are under `metric label` group).
Is there a way to filter by textPayload? 
Is there a reason why I can't filter by this field specially ?(I could not find any documentation explaining why some fields are accessible and others are not)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Severity and logName are predefined labels for metrics. That is why you can find them in the list. You can find references for this in documentation at page https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/logs-based-metrics/labels under "Default labels". Labels are available for filter and group by -fields.

If you want to use textPayload or part of it as filter or group by, you can create user-defined metrics and define custom labels based on textPayload. Then when you select the user-defined metric in metrics explorer, you can find your labels there.

Comment: thanks! The problem is that it will only consider logs created after the metric creation, but I want to perform a post-mortem.
Thanks anyway!